# Spark-Scala with Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, etl, cassandra-2.0

I am beginner with Spark, Scala and Cassandra. I am working with ETL programming.
Now my project ETL POCs required Spark, Scala and Cassandra. I configured Cassandra with my ubuntu system in /usr/local/Cassandra/* and after that I installed Spark and Scala. Now I am using Scala editor to start my work, I created simply load a file in landing location, but after that I am trying to connect with cassandra in scala but I am not getting an help how we can connect and process the data in destination database?.

Any one help me Is this correct way? or some where I am wrong? please help me to how we can achieve this process with above combination.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) to your pom or sbt by reading instruction, then work this way

Import this in your file

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
```

spark scala file

```
object SparkCassandraConnector {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf(true)
  .setAppName("UpdateCassandra")
  .setMaster("spark://spark:7077") // spark server
  .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb","67108864")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.3.167") // cassandra host
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")

// connecting with cassandra for spark and sql query
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

//    Load data from node publish table
val df = spark
  .read
  .cassandraFormat( "table_nmae",  "keyspace_name")
  .load()
 }
}
```

**This will work for spark 2.2 and cassandra 2**

Answer (score 0):

you can perform this easly with [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md)